# How is best way generate a short name e.g value of property in database

Tags: java, database, stringbuilder

I have pure Java question altough i work with JSF stuff,managed beans,DB etc.but on this doesn't matter.
So i want display on of my row in DataTable a short name of my property which is in database like 'name' or another String fields,

eg. lets supposse we have in database a table Person >> person has 'name' property, In this table i create another field 'shortname' >> in here will be stored a short name of value from 'name' 
So for example value in 'name ' field is

> John

now in my 'shortname' property must be a short-name e.g JOH so first three letters i want store here.

Can i ask for some Java pattern what i may use in my controller method to display value in this kind of form? its useful for this som kind of String Builder class? i not sure about this that work also with DB values
Thanks a lot for yours post.

Comment: See this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 1):

In this way you can achieve with String class

```
yourStringVar.substring(0,3).toUpperCase()
```

Comment: thank you for fast response, i ask one more question,its similar but is about display value of id, i want it show these values with prefix '0' and,so how about integer values in this case?

Comment: int id= 12;
String s = "0" + id;